# Android Studio: product flavor combination with more than two flavor dimensions and build type

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, adt, source-sets

When working with more than 2 flavors, ADT/gradle doesn't currently support overriding with a subset of the flavors.

i.e. I have flavors apple/orange, red/green, bad/good. Then I can have resource/java folders as:

```
apple
orange
appleRedBad
orangeRedGood
```

But by default it is not possible to have

```
appleRed
```

One has to create all possible combinations, copying the files.

This was [previously discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022139/android-studio-product-flavor-combination-with-more-than-two-flavor-dimensions), and the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62677302/1816603) was proposed, which works great:

```
android {
    …
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavors = variant.productFlavors
        def fruit = flavors[0].name
        def color = flavors[1].name
        def version = flavors[2].name

        def fruitColorSrcSet = fruit + color.capitalize()
        def srcSet = fruitColorSrcSet + version.capitalize()
        android.sourceSets."$srcSet".java.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet/java"
        android.sourceSets."$srcSet".res.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet/res"
    }
}
```

However, I have some resource folders which are specific to the Release or Debug builds. E.g. "appleYellowDebug". I have tried adding variant.buildType.name to the source dir, but then since I'm still using the same android.sourceSets."$srcSet".java.srcDirs for both build type, the folder gets added to both debug and release builds:

```
android.sourceSets."$srcSet".java.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet" + variant.buildType.name.capitalize() + "/java"
```

How can I add a folder only to a release or debug source set? Is that possible at all? Right now I am adding each of the flavors+build types to the source set, but this is very verbose; I'd rather add it in a generic form as per above.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the solution, which is just that the build types add new source sets, such as appleRedDebug. So all I had to do was to add the resource folder to android.sourceSets."$srcSetBuildType", as in:

```
android {
    …
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavors = variant.productFlavors
        def fruit = flavors[0].name
        def color = flavors[1].name
        def version = flavors[2].name

        def fruitColorSrcSet = fruit + color.capitalize()
        def srcSet = fruitColorSrcSet + version.capitalize()

        // flavor combinations
        android.sourceSets."$srcSet".java.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet/java"
        android.sourceSets."$srcSet".res.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet/res"

        // flavor + build type combinations
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        def srcSetBuildType = fruitColorSrcSet + version.capitalize() + buildType.capitalize()
        android.sourceSets."$srcSetBuildType".res.srcDirs += "src/$fruitColorSrcSet" + buildType.capitalize() + "/res"
    }
}
```